# Transaction syntax error, want to roll back delete

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok I changed to MCRE....

`CREATE TABLE 
id INT
user_id INT
updated_at DATE`

Example Data...

`id user_id updated_at`

`1 20 2019-09-02 01:00:00`

`2 20 2019-09-03 04:00:00`

`3 22 2019-09-04 03:00:00`

`4 22 2019-09-05 05:00:00`

`5 20 2019-09-10 01:00:00`

I want to keep 1 row per user and just most recently updated, and put it in rollback to test.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM table
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT a.id FROM (
            SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) FROM table GROUP BY user_id)
        a);
END TRANSACTION;
```

`mysql  Ver 8.0.18 for macos10.?? on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

Comment: I reject the premise of the question: `SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) FROM table GROUP BY user_id` is nonsensical. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I gave you an example, trying to remove duplicates, retain only one row per user_id. Also how is it nonsensical? It works and returns the ids I want to delete

Comment: @cwybr See my reply, you have to change `BEGIN TRANSACTION` with `START TRANSACTION` and `END TRANSACTION` with `ROLLBACK`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Change `END TRANSACTION` with `ROLLBACK`.
- Change `BEGIN TRANSACTION` with `START TRANSACTION` (`BEGIN` is an alias, `BEGIN TRANSACTION` is nothing).

See [MySQL documentation for transaction statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html).

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM table
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT a.id FROM (
            SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) FROM table GROUP BY user_id)
        a);
ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following (slightly modified, by way of example):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,updated_at DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,20,'2019-09-22 01:00:00'),
(2,20,'2019-09-13 04:00:00'),
(3,22,'2019-09-14 03:00:00'),
(4,22,'2019-09-05 05:00:00'),
(5,22,'2019-09-20 01:00:00');

SELECT id, MAX(updated_at) n FROM my_table GROUP BY user_id;
+----+------------+
| id | n          |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2019-09-22 |
|  3 | 2019-09-20 |
+----+------------+
```

There is no row in the data set with an id of 3, and an updated_at of '2019-09-20 01:00:00'. That is what I mean by nonsensical.

The following is an example of a valid query:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(updated_at) n FROM my_table GROUP BY user_id;
```

This can then be used (for instance) within a subquery...

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , MAX(updated_at) updated_at
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) b
    ON b.user_id = a.user_id 
   AND b.updated_at = a.updated_at;
```

You could use the above to create a new table with just the data you wished to retain. If feasible, then this approach is typically orders of magnitude faster then a DELETE.

Comment: Yes but this is the most recent update for that user which is what I wanted. How do you suggest I alter the query and put it into a tx? ty strawberry

Answer (score -1):

You should Try COMMIT TRANSACTION and not END TRANSACTION

Comment: I thought we weren't supposed to commit if we want to rollback? btw no switching does not remove err

Comment: There is a logic behind TRANSACTION Scope. The perfect way to do this is with a TRY CATCH . You can then start with BEGIN TRANSACTION and then if everything is smooth you continue with COMMIT TRANSACTION otherwise ROLLBACK in the catch block. You can read more here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
but in any case END TRANSACTION is wrong Syntax